# Efficiently Doing Diffusion on a 2d map in Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I'm pretty new to Python, so I'm doing a project in it. Part of it includes a diffusion across a map. I'm implementing it by going through and making the current tile equal to .2 * the sum of its neighbors n,w,s,e. If I was doing this in C, I'd just do a double for loop that loops through an array doing arr[i*width + j] = arr of j+1, j-1, i+i, i-1 the neighbors) and have several different arrays that I'd do the same thing for (different qualities of the map I'd be changing). However, I'm not sure if this is really the fastest way in Python. Some people I have asked suggest stuff like numPy, but the width probably won't be more than ~200 (so 40-50k elements max) and I wasn't sure if the overhead is worth it. I don't really know any builtin functions to do what I want. Any advice?

edit: This will be very dense i.e. every spot is going to have a non-trivial calculation

Comment: Numpy all the way. 50,000 elements is quite a lot considering you'll have to look at 9 neighbors (which is 450,000 lookups).

Answer (score 3):

This is quite simple to arrange with [NumPy](https://numpy.org/). The function [np.roll](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html#numpy-roll) returns a copy of the array, "rolled" in a specified direction.

For example, given the array `x`,

```
x=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
# array([[0, 1, 2],
#        [3, 4, 5],
#        [6, 7, 8]])
```

you can roll the columns to the right with

```
np.roll(x,shift=1,axis=1)
# array([[2, 0, 1],
#        [5, 3, 4],
#        [8, 6, 7]])
```

Using np.roll, boundaries are wrapped like on a torus. If you do not want wrapped boundaries, you could pad the array with an edge of zeros, and reset the edge to zero before every iteration.

```
import numpy as np

def diffusion(arr):
    while True:
        arr+=0.2*np.roll(arr,shift=1,axis=1) # right
        arr+=0.2*np.roll(arr,shift=-1,axis=1) # left
        arr+=0.2*np.roll(arr,shift=1,axis=0) # down
        arr+=0.2*np.roll(arr,shift=-1,axis=0) # up
        yield arr

N=5
initial=np.random.random((N,N))
for state in diffusion(initial):
    print(state)
    raw_input()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use convolution.

```
from numpy import *
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

mapArr=array(map)
kernel=array([[0  , 0.2,   0],
              [0.2,   0, 0.2],
              [0  , 0.2,   0]])
diffused=convolve2d(mapArr,kernel,boundary='wrap')
```

Is this for the ants challenge? If so, in the ants context, convolve2d worked ~20 times faster than the loop, in my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This modification to unutbu's code maintains constant the global sum of the array while diffuses the values of it:

```
        import numpy as np

        def diffuse(arr, d):
            contrib = (arr * d)
            w = contrib / 8.0
            r = arr - contrib
            N = np.roll(w, shift=-1, axis=0)
            S = np.roll(w, shift=1, axis=0)
            E = np.roll(w, shift=1, axis=1)
            W = np.roll(w, shift=-1, axis=1)
            NW = np.roll(N, shift=-1, axis=1)
            NE = np.roll(N, shift=1, axis=1)
            SW = np.roll(S, shift=-1, axis=1)
            SE = np.roll(S, shift=1, axis=1)
            diffused = r + N + S + E + W + NW + NE + SW + SE
            return diffused
```